# Why isn't Gulp watching a file and moving code to the desired location?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Here I have my gulp file doing basic things such as compressing my css, uglifying my javascript and such. It seems to be updating my files, from `src/`, and moving them in, `build/`, for my CSS files, but not for javascript ones. I can't seem to find a problem. No error codes or anything is being given.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'), //Task runner
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'), //Minimizies JS
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'), //Compiles to CSS
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'); // Minimize images

//Error look-out
function errorLog(error){
  console.error.bind(error);
  this.emit('end');
}

// Scripts
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  gulp.src('src/js/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .on('error', errorLog)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});

// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function(){
  return sass('src/css/*.sass',{
    style: 'compressed'
  })
  .on('error', errorLog)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});

// Images
gulp.task('imagemin', function(){
  gulp.src('src/images/*')
  .pipe(imagemin())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images'))
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('src/js/*.js', ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch('src/css/*.sass', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('src/images/**/*', ['images']);
});

//Run task
gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'styles', 'imagemin', 'watch']);
```

Screenshot of my project root:
[image]

Screenshot of my task runner output:
[image]

Comment: just to double check, all your files are in `src/js` and they all do have `.js` on the end?

Comment: @Markasoftware yes, just added a screenshot of my file setup.

Comment: what do you mean not for the JS ones? Updated code is not reflected? Code not minified? What exactly is the discrepancy?

Comment: @scniro The CSS/SASS part of the gulp file works exactly how I want. It takes my input, compresses it, and moves it into my build/css folder. For my javascript files, after I enter some test code inside my .js file and save, I see terminal reads that it has updated, but the destination file (in my build/js folder) remains unchanged.

Comment: does the `scripts` task run successfully on it own aside from the watch? e.g. run `gulp scripts`

Comment: Are you making changes to the `.js` files? If not your `watch` task won't run the `scripts` task.

Comment: @scniro I'll try that.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Yes I'm making changes.

Comment: @EugeneRoss cool! let us know if you find anything out on that task

Comment: @scniro running `gulp scripts` separately isn't working either. Nothing in the destination file.

Comment: @EugeneRoss try to `return gulp.src('src/js/*.js')`. Seem to be omitting the return call

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it appears the `/build/js/*.js` and `/build/css/*.css` files have changed, as indicated by their green coloring. But the `src` directory has no changed files. Are you editing the files in `src/`?

Comment: They were changed manually by me to test something out. Yes, I'm editing the files in src/ only.